# Нужна точность:  float64 -> float96

Tags: python

По умолчанию питон использует для расчетов тип float64. Вопрос: можно ли по умолчанию поставить использование типа float96 или float128?

проблема вот еще в чем: почему-то между float64 и float96 нет никакой разницы в результатах. то есть изначально число Decimal, потом я перевожу его в float32 - в результате 8 знаков после запятой, потом Decimal пробую перевести в float64 - в результате 14 знаков после запятой, и если переводить в float96, то тоже 14 знаков после запятой, а мне нужно около 20. что делать и чем объясняется одинаковый результат float64 - float96?
и почему если питоновский float64 есть аналог double в сишнике у меня получается 14 знаков после запятой, а не 16?

Comment: похоже на [XY вопрос](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/795/23044). Если `decimal.Decimal` используете, то вы уже можете любую точность указать. Корень проблемы может быть в игнорировании ошибки представления для чисел с плавающей точкой (например, `0.1` (десятичное) не может быть представлена точно, если эту дробь в `float` тип перевести, который использует двоичное представление -- это периодическая дробь в двоичной системе и она не имеет конечного представления). Приведите конкретные примеры, что получается и что Вы вместо этого ожидаете.

Answer (score 1):

Да, можно, взять float128 из numpy:

```
from numpy import float128
```

Comment: проблема вот еще в чем:
почему-то между float64 и float96 нет никакой разницы в результатах.
то есть изначально число Decimal, потом я перевожу его в float32 - в результате 8 знаков после запятой, потом Decimal пробую перевести в float64 - в результате 14 знаков после запятой, и если переводить в float96, то тоже 14 знаков после запятой, а мне нужно около 20. что делать и чем объясняется одинаковый результат float64 - float96?

и почему если питоновский float64 есть аналог double в сишнике у меня получается 14 знаков после запятой, а не 16?

Comment: Это сколько же у вас разрядов, что под мантиссу остаётся 16 байт?!

Comment: целая часть равна нулю, а после запятой много разрядов (минимум 16), например, число 0,0012345678911111

Comment: Пользуйтесь decimal или float'ом из numpy. У флоата только 53 бита мантиссы.

Comment: я и использую float из numpy - float64 и float96, проблемы, которые возникают написаны выше, они почему-то не дают необходимую точность, хотя теоретически должны (float64 уже должен давать 16 знаков после запятой, а float96 и того больше, но почему-то они вообще никак не отличаются друг от друга). а decimal не могу использовать.

Comment: Проверяте numpy:
In [1]: from numpy import float128
In [2]: k = float128('0.01111111111111111111111111111111111')
In [3]: k
Out[3]: 0.011111111111111111535

Comment: Хум, не знаю, если честно. Попробуйте поставить scipy ещё: http://scipy.org/Download

Comment: и еще такая к вам просьба. не могли бы вы у себя проверить сколько знаков после запятой оставляет тип флоат96? спасибо

Answer (score 0):

А зачем, если не секрет?
Можете посмотреть на пакет [bigfloat](http://packages.python.org/bigfloat/).

Comment: сторонние пакеты не могу использовать.
точность нужна чтобы проверить некоторые теоретические выкладки.